# Upgrading from Entity Framework 4 to 5 resulted in error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

After upgrading to EF 5 I keep getting `Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details'` in a particular instance of my code.

It turns out I have a field that is a NVARCHAR nullable in the database and it marked has [Required] with Data annotation in a partial class. The field in question is set to null programmatically. This worked fine in EF4 as it was validated against the database model (NVARCHAR nullable).

I need to keep that field marked as [Required] because it also takes user inputs in other instances.

What are my options? Can I ignore that attribute/validation error right before `SaveChanges()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why it is strongly recommended that you use View models, rather than passing your entities directly to the view.  Your view and data model have different requirements, and trying to use the same model with validation causes problems.

Instead, remove the required attribute from your data model and create a View model that has the required on it, then use something like AutoMapper to map between them.

Comment: I'm already using a view model. I just have two views: one requires that field the other doesn't. If I remove [Required] from the view model. How can I enforce that for one of my views? (add a new validation rule in the controller? not data annotation)

Comment: @James: If you are using view model you have a separate view model for each view requiring different validations. If not, you are not using view model - at least you are not using it correctly. Data annotations for view validation on entities are complete misconception.

Comment: maybe I'm not using it correctly. Do you have a link to a tutorial?

Comment: @James - Well if you're using a separate view model, then you should remove the Required attribute from your data model.  Your data model has to match how your Database is designed.  You use the Required attribute only on your view model.